# Por que no verifica en mysqli conexion php

Tags: php, mysqli

¿Por qué no verifica que el usuario existe? Da como resultado un valor vacío, pero si existe es como si no ejecutara la consulta y cae en `Die` existiendo el usuario.

```
   <?php
$certa      = $_POST['certa'];
if (isset($_POST['SCN'])) 
{   
    include_once "../includes/mysql_conex.php";
    $cert1 = mysqli_query ('SELECT * FROM cloud_data_avanzado 
    WHERE Usuario = \'' . $certa . '\'');
    $cert2 = mysqli_query ('SELECT * FROM cloud_data 
    WHERE Usuario = \'' . $certa . '\''); 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($cert1)==0 or mysqli_num_rows($cert2)==0)
        die ('Disculpe o Usted no es parte del Staff o simplemente su usario y Contrase&ntilde;a son incorrectos. Aver algo 04032019');
    else
    {
        die('Exito al conectar');
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<br><br>
<form action="<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>" method="POST">
<table>
<tr><td>Tu UserID de Staff:</td><td><input type="text" placeholder = "UserID o Usuario Staff" name="certa" /></td></tr>
</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Enviar&nbsp;Consulta&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" name="

SC" /></p>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**INCLUDE**

```
<?php
$conexion = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "dyaforza_forza", "Tresado456", "dyaforza_almacen");
if (!$conexion)
{
    printf("La Base de Datos No esta Conectada por favor informese de este error al DEV con el Codigo del error <font color=red>SFGAHHAHH562</font>.", mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

**MySQL**

```
 -- Consulta
 create table cloud_data_avanzado (
RowID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Usuario varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (RowID)
);
INSERT cloud_data_avanzado (Usuario) VALUES('test');

 -- Consulta
 create table cloud_data (
RowID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Usuario varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (RowID)
);
INSERT cloud_data_avanzado (Usuario) VALUES('otro');
```

Nota: se cambio IF a resultado doble para ver si no die, se comprobo que con una consulta si lee la variable.

Comment: Hola Juan, ya comprobaste qué es lo que te está retornando `$certa` al ingresarlo como parámetro en tu consulta?

Comment: si lo hice con print pero no se si tiene que ver algo con espacios o mayusculas o algo asi por el estilo.

Comment: Deberías de utilizar `var_dump` ya que proporciona información sobre el tamaño y tipo de datos de la variable y, en el caso de arrays y objetos, de los elementos que la componen; prueba y nos dices que te muestra como resultado.

Comment: Tengo la impresión de que tu query esta fallando y por eso te devuelve FALSE que se interpreta como vacío.

Comment: Como se usa var_dump?

Comment: Perdon me informaron que la consulta la plantee mal ya que era doble if

Comment: Avisen si la planteo de nuevo o la dejo como esta ya que la anterior estaba bien el script pero con doble es problema de mysqli_num_rows

Comment: @JuanCarlosVillamizarAlvarez cual es tu problema ahora?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cambia la consulta

```
$cert = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM cloud_data_avanzado WHERE Usuario ='.$certa.'');
```

creo le falto una comilla simple ¿no? ¿o tiene que ser doble comilla?